# Hide post that links multiple Facebook friends

Tags: facebook

Say there is a Facebook photo that friends are talking about, but you decide you do not really want to see in the stream. Will hiding the post, hide **all activity** related to that post ?

Example:

- Photos tags
- Likes
- Comments

I tried hiding the person but Facebook adjusts accordingly and brings the same post back but instead as from a next Facebook friend linked in the same photo either as a comment or a photo tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the "Hide this post" functionality is that it will hide that post and all future comments, like etc on that particular post.

If another friend posted the same picture again you would have to hide that post too. Facebook isn't intelligent enough to recognise, what are essentially, duplicate posts.